# Connection with web address gives "No route to host" but connection with IP works

Tags: ssh, routing

I try to open an SSH connection with

```
ssh xx.at -p nn
```

and get `no route to host`.
If I inquire about the host with

```
host xx.at
```

the answer is `xx.at has address ipnnn`
and the connection with

```
ssh ipnn -p nn
```

works. 
`xx.at` is a web address which is dynamically bound to the current IP. The setting is correct (checked).

What can be the cause? (I am on Debian Stretch, using OpenSSH)

Answer (score 0):

The cause was simply an entry in /etc/hosts, which I had to enter for a problem with a DSL modem in another location and I had not removed after moving the computer.

The lines in the `/etc/hosts` said

```
10.nn.nn.nn  xx.at
```

after removing it, the ssh connection worked. 
stupid mistake...